# PersistenceUnitLoadingException - Error creating EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I spent the last days searching for an error, but I'm not able to find it. I have to say that I'm a total newbie to JPA and that this is my first project, which I created following a tutorial but having an unexplained mistake.

I use Eclipse and Eclipselink and connected a runniny mySql-database

My code:

```
package com.tutorialspoint.eclipselink.service;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import com.tutorialspoint.eclipselink.entity.Employee;

public class CreateEmployee {

    public static void main(String []args){
        EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("tutorialspoint_JPA_Eclipselink");
        EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager();
        entitymanager.getTransaction().begin();

        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setId(1201);
        e.setName("Gopal");
        e.setSalary(40000);
        e.setDegree("Technical Manager");
        entitymanager.persist(e);
        entitymanager.getTransaction().commit();
        entitymanager.close();
        emfactory.close();
    }

}
```

The `persistence.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" x   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="tutorialspoint_JPA_Eclipselink" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> 
        <class>com.tutorialspoint.eclipselink.entity.Employee</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="removed"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services -     2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):         org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for     persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1b1f1f12
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception         [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):     org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [tutorialspoint_JPA_Eclipselink] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at     org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSear    chingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at     org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(P    ersistenceProvider.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(Persi    stenceProvider.java:183)
    at     javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at     javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at     com.tutorialspoint.eclipselink.service.CreateEmployee.main(CreateEmployee.java:1    1)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-    28018]         (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):     org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit     [tutorialspoint_JPA_Eclipselink] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at     org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFaile    dPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2023)
    at         org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityMana    gerSetupImpl.java:2014)
    at     org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPA    Initializer.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(P    ersistenceProvider.java:100)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services -     2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):     org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit     [tutorialspoint_JPA_Eclipselink] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at     org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(E    ntityManagerSetupException.java:231)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at     org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatformDetector.checkPlatform(N    oServerPlatformDetector.java:28)
    at     org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.ServerPlatformUtils.detectServerPlatform    (ServerPlatformUtils.java:44)
    at     org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateServerPlatform    (EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:973)
    at     org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityMana    gerSetupImpl.java:1718)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Where did you put your persistence.xml? Please write the file path.

Comment: the persistence.xml file is in the META-INF-foulder and under JPA-Content

Comment: It is important your persistence.xml to be here: 'projectroot'/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml . To me it looks like it doesn't find the "tutorialspoint_JPA_Eclipselink" persistence file...

Comment: the path is: tutorialspoint_JPA_Eclipselink/src/META-INF
how do I move it to the path you suggested?

Comment: Ok. Please try and change your path to this: src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml And let me know if it works

Comment: If you cannot find it, create it.

Comment: it still doesn't work, but now I get another error:
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named tutorialspoint_JPA_Eclipselink
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
 at com.tutorialspoint.eclipselink.service.CreateEmployee.main(CreateEmployee.java:15)

Comment: Ok, so you can move it back where it was in the first place. The error that is now stated is that it cannot find the perssistance file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably misplaced the EclipseLink jar-file.

The NPE (NullPointerException) stems from line 28 in `org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatformDetector` (see the last `Caused by` in the error you posted). This line is shown on GrepCode [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.0/org/eclipse/persistence/platform/server/NoServerPlatformDetector.java) and shows:

`PrivilegedAccessHelper.getClassLoaderForClass(NoServerPlatformDetector.class).toString();`

and looking into the `PrivilegedAccessHelper.getClassLoaderForClass` method shows that the line can be re-written as:

`NoServerPlatformDetector.class.getClassLoader().toString();`

Now, `getClassLoader` can return `null` in which case `toString()` will cause the NPE. `getClassLoader` returns `null` if the EclipseLink jar-file was loaded using the bootstrap classloader (see [this wiki-page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader) about the bootstrap classloader). This makes me believe you placed the EclipseLink jar-file in the `<JAVA_HOME>/jre/lib` directory, or in Eclipse-terms, made it part of the "JRE System Library".

Right-click the project in Eclipse, select Properties, select "Java Build Path", open tab "Libraries", expand the "JRE System Library" (or something similar) and make sure the EclipseLink jar-file is NOT shown. Add the EclipseLink jar-file using the "Add (external) JARs" button (this should ensure the jar-file is loaded using the system classloader instead of the bootstrap classloader).

On a side node, the `NoServerPlatformDetector` causing the NPE is flawed: the next line shows `if (loaderStr != null` but this check is redundant since the `toString()` will never return `null`. In other words: the programmer was aware that `getClassLoader` can return null, but forgot that `toString()` will cause a NPE in this case.

Comment: thanks for your answer but the EclipseLink jar-file already is added as an external jar and was never part of the JRE system library

Answer (score 0):

thats the right solution. If you put the eclipselink.jar and/or the javax.persistence.jar in a User Library then eclipse cant find the EntityManagerFactory. So you have to remove the user library and put the jar files in the JRE System Library.

Right Click on project > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Java Build Path (Libraries) > Add external Jar > add eclipselink.jar under JRE System Library and voila...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was generated by not using the "annotation" `@`  in the declarative of the class. In my case, the fields type `DATE`, dont take the "@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)" on the atribute  in the class Java.  When i put this annotation, the problem  finish.